# ReplayKit 2 Broadcast pairing service is not working

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I have integrated Broadcast pairing service in my application using ReplayKit 2. When we start a new session an alert prompt for the permission to accept/deny. Broadcast setup popover will present once we accept the permission. In the application window doesn't load anything at all.

Here is my code:

```
func goOnline(){
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        RPBroadcastActivityViewController.load(withPreferredExtension: "xx.xx.xx.xxx") { (activityVC, error) in
            activityVC?.delegate = self
            self.present(activityVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing one more issue, Once the broadcast extension is discarded we could not interact with app. App doesnt respond touch event.